# js Tree error for function .jstree()

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, jstree

I am implementing a jstree in mvc4, but when I run my application no tree view is displayed. I have tried to track the error with Firebug and found the following error:

```
"TypeError: $(...).jstree is not a function $("#divtree").jstree();"
```

Comment: You need to include the jstree source.

Comment: yes.. i have already done this
e.g:<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.jstree.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: first of all, you should try including the javascript file for jstree function to work

Comment: Monika, can u check whether the path u have provided is valid ?

Comment: you could also try expanding the script tag in firebug to see it the contents of js file loaded successfully

Comment: thanks for reply.. i have checked in firebug js file loaded successfully.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Follow the guide on https://github.com/vakata/jstree

```
<script src="/path/to/jstree.min.js"></script>
<script>
    jQuery(function($) {
         ("#divtree").jstree();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: i am using the same way,but still no success..:(

Comment: silly mistake..i have added jstree.js file again and changed script path location..and it worked.. :) Thanks...

Comment: I have Same Problem, i use it on wordpress !

Comment: I suppose the new script path location that you have finally used is the CDNJS one: (http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.3.3/jstree.min.js)

Otherwise the code provide by Nix seems not to work. 

If you want to verify it made a checkout from [tag 3.3.3](https://github.com/vakata/jstree/tree/3.3.3) , go to the dist folder and make a  `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8050 dist`

Yo will verify in the logs that somehow the browser make an extra load of `jstree.js` as you have noted. I don't know why doesn't happen with online version even when they are the same file.

Comment: Sorry it was a copy/paste mistake in the line linking the external javascript. I was using link tag instead of the script one.